# How to generate deprecated warning for a method in a COM interface (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, deprecated

We are using a "COM-like" model where I work, as we generally follow COM rules, but do not perform MIDL compiling and do not target other languages than c/c++. As such, I know I can always bend the rules to suit my needs, but I try not to since we might want to become truly COM-compliant someday and if that day comes, we want it to be as painless as possible.

I want to print out a warning when anyone compiles code using a certain method from a specific interface. In c++ (we only support Microsoft compiler), we would add `__declspec(deprecated)` before the function declaration to achieve our goal.

Can I just add this in front of my interface method declaration or is there a better, more COM way to do that?

I would also like to know if only adding `__declspec(deprecated)` in front of the method is enough to force users to recompile (I would like to avoid that, if possible).

Thanks

**Update**

I tried using `__declspec(deprecated)` in front of my method declaration like this:

```
struct Interface : public IUnknown
{
    __declspec(deprecated) virtual HRESULT __stdcall OldMethod
    (
        int Arg1;
        int Arg2;
    ) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall NewMethod
    (
        //arguments...
    ) = 0;
}
```

With this way of deprecating a method, I get no compiler warning at all when trying to use OldMethod. Is there a limitation that I don't know about using `__declspec(deprecated)` with pure virtual methods?

Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

`__declspec(deprecated)` is a source-level feature of the MS C/C++ compiler, and won't affect the binary layout (ABI) of anything - so users will not have to recompile. The effect is to issue a compile-time warning to anyone calling that method via including your C++ header file. It will have no effect on people using your object as a COM object without including your header, e.g. from another language. I don't believe COM/IDL provides an analogous 'deprecated' attribute itself.

So in summary, you may as well add the attribute for the benefit of the C++ users, but if you ever provide for general COM consumers, they will have to rely on documentation you provide to know that the method is deprecated.

Comment: When I try using `__declspec(deprecated)` in the header file declaring the interface method I want to deprecate (which is a pure virtual method), I get no warning when compiling code that uses that method. However, if I use the `#pragma deprecated` macro, I get a warning. This is better than nothing, but usage of the macro is less precise than with __declspec, since with that one I can specify a custom warning message. Also, the `#pragma deprecated` macro will target any identifier that has the name of my method, even if not from the interface. Do you have any ideas about why this happens?

Comment: And thanks for your answer. I will mark it as the winning one if no one else give me a solution as to what I can do to be able to use the `__declspec(deprecated)` directive, since your explanation is very good.

Comment: @franmon: You don't show your call-site code. Are you calling the method on an object of static type Interface* (or Interface&)?

Comment: I do the following: `Interface* pI = NULL; CoCreateInstance(GUID, args..., &pI);` to create an object of class Class that inherits from Interface, and then `pI->OldMethod(x1,x2);`.

Comment: I will check at work tomorrow if there is anything in between CoCreateInstance and the OldMethod call... like a QueryInterface call or something. But I don't think so. Should it matter?

Comment: I can confirm the sequence of calls I explained in my last comments are accurate. We tried it with multiple of our interfaces, always with the same result.

Comment: You must be right then - that MSVC ignores `deprecated` on pure methods (or even on any virtual method call?) If so, I consider that a compiler bug personally.

Comment: It seems that it is supposed to work with virtual method calls, and there may have been a bug in older versions of MSVC which caused it not to, but if you're using VC10 with the latest SP, I believe it should work as you are intending. The generated warning will not prevent successful compilation, so make sure it's not getting drowned in other compiler output?